# How use SwitchNavigator behavior with react-navigation 5 using current state of route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I want to set one background for all screens in my app. So I put this background once before the stack navigator and make all screens with transparent background. I use react-navigation v5 and it hasn't a switch navigator now, which can resolve my problem. I want to switch screens and see my background behind them. 
I try to use `useNavigationState` hook, but that's not working outside the navigator. How can I handle my problem?

Some code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Svg, { Polygon, Defs, LinearGradient, Stop } from 'react-native-svg';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { AuthContainer, MenuContainer, ProfileContainer } from './src/screens';
import store from './src/store/store';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Auth: undefined;
  Menu: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill]}>
          <Svg
            viewBox='0 0 1 1'
            width='100%'
            height='100%'
            preserveAspectRatio='none'
          >
            <Defs>
              <LinearGradient id='grad' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='1'>
                <Stop offset='0' stopColor='#3A4B6C' stopOpacity='1' />
                <Stop offset='1' stopColor='#419D9A' stopOpacity='1' />
              </LinearGradient>
            </Defs>
            <Polygon points='0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0' fill='url(#grad)' />
          </Svg>
        </View>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName='Auth'
          headerMode='none'
          screenOptions={{
            cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
            cardOverlayEnabled: true,
          }}
          mode='modal'
        >
          <Stack.Screen name='Auth' component={AuthContainer} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Menu' component={MenuContainer} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Profile' component={ProfileContainer} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation can help you with this:

[Upgrading from 4.x | React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#switch-navigator)